# Starting multiple timers and know which one has ended in C

Tags: c, linux, timer, signals

I need to be able to start multiple timers simultaneously and know specifically if a timer has stopped or is still going.

```
#define RESEND_TIMEOUT  5

void timer_set_timeout(timer_t * timer, uint32_t timeout);
void timer_start(timer_t * timer);
bool timer_complete(timer_t * timer);
void signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc);

int main() {
    timer_t resend_timer;
    printf("starting timer\n");
    timer_start(&resend_timer);
    timer_set_timeout(RESEND_TIMEOUT);
    while(1) {

    if (timer_complete(&resend_timer))
        break;
    }
}

void timer_set_timeout(timer_t * timer, uint32_t timeout)
{
    struct itimerspec it_val;
    it_val.it_value.tv_sec = timeout;
    it_val.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    it_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    it_val.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
     if (timer_settime(*timer, 0, &it_val, NULL) == -1) {
         errExit("Could not set timeout");
     }
}

void timer_start(timer_t * timer)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct sigevent sev;

    // establish signal handler
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL) == -1)
       errExit("Failed to establish signal handler");

    // create timer
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timer;

    if(timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &sev, timer) == -1) {
        errExit("Could not start timer");
    }
}

// return true if timer ended
bool timer_complete(timer_t * timer)
{
    if(timer_getoverrun(*timer) == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

void signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    printf("Timer ran out!\n");
    signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
}
```

The signal handler runs after 5 seconds, but I am unable to know if the timer has ended or not using timer_complete.
I have tried with:        int timer_gettime(timer_t timerid, struct itimerspec *curr_value)
but I do not know what to pass for curr_value. I tried declaring an itimerspec but it gives the same result as getoverrun.

I also tried with the flag TIMER_ABSTIME for timer_settime, but the timer expires instantly for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what signifies the timer being completed.

Starting at the beginning, the timer has 2 sets of values.  One set is the time in future that the timer will go off; the other is interval value that is used to reload the first set afer the timer goes off.  If the first set is used but the interval values are set to zeros then it is by definition a one-shot timer.  If the interval values are non-zero then the timer is going to reload and fire in perpetuity until you shut it off.  You shut it off by setting all values to zero with `timer_settimer`.

So in your timer_complete should look something like this:

```
// return true if timer ended
bool timer_complete(timer_t * timer)
{
    struct itimerspec its;

    if (timer_gettime(*timer, &its) == -1)
    {
        perror("timer_settime");
        exit(1);
    }

    If ((its.it_value.tv_sec == 0)  &&
        (its.it_value.tv_nsec == 0) &&
        (its.it_interval.tv_sec == 0) &&
        (its.it_interval.tv_nsec == 0))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Overruns are a different animal.  Basically, the OS is not going to queue the timer signal multiples times, even realtime signals, because there are potentially just too many.  Overrun tells you how many times a timer went off, that is potentially queued signals, occurred before your program received the signal.

Comment: It isn't necessary to test the interval fields.  timer_settimer(3) says: "If new_value->it_value specifies a zero value (i.e., both subfields are zero), then the timer is disarmed."